# Stop Function Call

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to stop my function call after executing "exit" user input. But failed to achieve this.
Below is my code.

```
> def ufun():
>         while True:
>                 uipt = str(raw_input('Please enter your choice? [y|n]:'))
>                 if uresp == "y":
>                         ufun.uipt = "y"
>                         break
>                 elif uresp == "n":
>                         ufun.uipt = "n"
>                         break
>                 else:
>                         print("Please enter either [y|n]") def anofunc():
> 
> def anofunc():
>         ulist = str(raw_input('Enter your choice [ALL|AB|BC|EXIT] : ')).upper()
>         ufun()
>         if ulist == "ALL":
>            #execute something
>         elif ulist == "AB":
>            #execute something
>         elif ulist == "BC":
>            #execute something
>         elif ulist == "EXIT":
>            return
>         else:
>            print "Please enter a valid option"
>            anofunc() 
anofunc()
```

So when I try exit the code while entering "EXIT" user input it asks me for "Please enter your choice? [y|n]:" which I don't want while exiting. I want my code to be exit right away.
Please help me if I can do this.

```
Enter your choice [ALL|AB|BC|EXIT] : exit
Please enter your choice? [y|n]:
```

Comment: Your calling ufun() right after the first prompt.. That may be why thats occurring

Comment: @ryekayo Ya actaully I want that function to executed only once even though I provide multiple user input like : AB|BC

Comment: In that case, I would add exit() right after your condition for EXIT.

Comment: @ryekayo As you suggested I tried the same but getting below error :
 
 exit()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Try return instead of exit(). My apologies, i thought that would be something that exists to kill the program..

Comment: @ryekayo No problem. But that is something I am already doing and facing the issue. Is there any way to exit the code without calling ufun() function. Please help.

Comment: Ok well one other thing im noticing is that your conditionals are NOT wrapped in single/double quotes. I would recommend doing that as your conditionals are not matching the strings you need it to. Thats step one, also, I assume that you are doing this in the Python command shell. Why not place this in a script and execute it instead? It'd certainly make troubleshooting easier for you

Comment: @ryekayo Sorry it was a typo. I have corrected now. And I am executing my script as in script only.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, the `>` made me assume you were doing all this in the python shell lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the condition of EXIT before you call the ufun() function. Right now, since the check is after, this calls the ufun() function which displays the text 'Please enter your choice? [y|n]:'.

Also, in your last condition in the ufun() function, I think you are trying to call the anofunc() function. For this, you just need to write anofunc() without the def. The def is used to define function definitions.

You are also constantly calling each function again and again which is I think not what you intended to do. If for example, you type something other than exit and type EXIT afterwards, you would still return the earlier function after the return call. If I am not wrong, you are trying to constantly ask the user what (s)he wants to do until they type exit.

One way to do this would be to bring the while loop to the anofunc() function:

```
def ufun():
    uipt = raw_input('Please enter your choice? [y|n]:')
    if uipt == "y":
        ufun.uipt = "y"
    elif uipt == "n":
        ufun.uipt = "n"
    else:
        print("Please enter either [y|n]")

def anofunc():
    while True:
        ulist = raw_input('Enter your choice [ALL|AB|BC|EXIT] : ').upper()
        if ulist == "EXIT":
            break
        ufun()
        if ulist == "ALL":
            #execute something
        elif ulist == "AB":
            #execute something
        elif ulist == "BC":
            #execute something
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid option")
anofunc()
```